# Fiddlercore: Session.LocalProcessID does not match System.Diagnostics.Process.Id

Tags: c#, pid, fiddlercore

I am trying to make a web traffic tool using the FiddlerCore dll. I want to filter my results by the ProcessID so that only traffic from the desired browser instance is recorded.

I use System.Diagnostics.Process to launch the user specified webpage in IE.

```
Process IEProc = Process.Start("IExplore.exe", DesiredWebpage);
IEProcID = IEProc.Id;
```

When a fiddler session has been completed, I check to see if the fiddler Session.LocalProcessID matches the Process ID

```
private void FiddlerCapture_AfterSessionComplete(Session sess)
{
    if(sess.LocalProcessID == IEProcID)
    {
        //Add results to logfile
    }
}
```

However, the Process ID's never match and all Fiddler traffic is ignored.

Why doesn't the ID provided by Process.Start match the ID provided by Session.LocalProcessID? How can I get the correct ID from each source?

Answer (score 0):

`Process.Start` returns the process ID for the Internet Explorer Frame/Manager process. Traffic from tabs comes from a child Render process.

There's sadly no great way to achieve what you're trying to do because the Render process may even be parented to a different Frame process than the one you tried to start.